# accessing local variable outside of for loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function

```
$rootScope.getCurrency = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.records.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < data.records[i].columns.length; j++
        if (data.records[i].columns[j].fieldname == "Currency") {
          // Here I want to
          // return the values
          // if I do something like
          return data.records[i].columns[j].value
          // the loop exits on the first condition
          // and does not iterate over completely. If I put
          // return outside of the
          // for loops it says i, j are undefined.
          // How can I use the value outside of this loop
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have to use the returned value in my HTML for binding data.
My HTMl looks like:

```
ng-repeat i in someArray ng-if={{i.type==currency?getCurrency():''}}
```

Comment: What is it that you want the function to return? An array of values? One value?

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pushing the values to an array:

```
$rootScope.getCurrency = function() {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.records.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < data.records[i].columns.length; j++
            if (data.records[i].columns[j].fieldname == "Currency") {
                // Add to array
                result.push(data.records[i].columns[j].value); 
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```